# Como ler uma tabela de excel no pandas pulando as primeiras linhas, sem perder informações?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, planilha, ciência-de-dados

Olá, tenho um problema para resolver um pouco complicado, tenho varias tabelas xls na qual eu tenho que retirar alguns dados, essas tabelas estão com seu conteúdo organizado de forma estranha...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
TEXTE TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO
TEXTE TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO
TEXTE TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO

Alt. 280m
Lat. 1°1'S
Lon. 4°1'W

                    DADO 1          DADO 2
    HORA UTC        0000                0100
    18-dez-2004     23,0                24,0
    19-dez-2004     24,9                24,9
    20-dez-2004     26,1                26,1
    21-dez-2004     26,6                26,1
    22-dez-2004     22,3                22,4
    23-dez-2004     25,9                26,0
```

Essa tabela apresenta um grande titulo na parte superior, abaixo aparecem dados em vermelho que são importantes para minha pesquisa, logo em seguida uma linha com todos os títulos das colunas em azul no qual eu preciso ler, em amarelo e a hora que aquele dado foi coletado, em verde o dia.

Quando tento ler essas tabelas de forma convencional com python as colunas aparecem de forma embaraçosa por culpa do titulo e dos dados em vermelho, eu gostaria de poder ler esses dados.

Pensei em fazer um script para deletar as linhas que não me serão úteis e em seguida transportar os dados em vermelho para duas colunas separadas no final, ainda não sei como fazer isso, mas por algum motivo a primeira linha nuca e apagada com o meu df.drop(linha) do pandas read_excel.

Eu travei nesse problema e não sei como me virar, se devo limpar os dados ou se consigo tratar eles assim, muito obrigado a quem se dispor em ajudar.

Comment: Tales, você poderia disponibilizar as primeiras linhas da tabela?(pode copiar e colar as primeiras linhas com algum separador qualquer). Pela imagem, é muito difícil ver o problema

Comment: @Hartnäcking as tres primeiras linhas são mesclas das primeiras 6 colunas e apresentam 3 frases, são informações confidenciais de onde veio a tabela.

Comment: Sendo esse o caso (sigilo dos dados), recomendo que você faça um exemplo mínimo replicável. Instruções nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de contornar esse problema é usando a função `read_excel` do `pandas`, passando o parâmetro `skiprows` com o numero de linhas que queres ignorar antes da tabela começar na folha do excel:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",
                   sheet_name = "Sheet1",
                   skiprows = range(0, 10) # ignora as primeiras 10 linhas do excel
                   )
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! eu poderia pegar aqueles dados de (alt. lat. lon.) antes?

Comment: @talesmm14 Para pegar esses dados, acho que seria melhor você fazer um programa separado para abrir como uma string cada planilha e pegar os dados que te interessam usando regex. Tem um tutorial desse módulo nesse link: https://www.vooo.pro/insights/tutorial-sobre-expressoes-regulares-para-iniciantes-em-python/